# mysql procedure parameter text to using where condition

Tags: mysql, where-clause, procedure

i correr it by have error on column name by alias table name

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Type: mysqli_sql_exception
Message: Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'
call projects_view(20,0, "(p.created_at >= '2023-09-01' AND 
p.created_at <= '2023-09-17')") Error Code: 1054. Unknown 
column 'created_at' in 'field list'
```

Code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `projects_view`(IN 
  `lmt` INT, IN `ofst` INT, IN vfilter VARCHAR(1000))
BEGIN
    declare declared_in_param varchar(1000);
    declare lim int;
    declare ofs int;
    set @declared_in_param = vfilter;
    set @lim = lmt;
    set @ofs = ofst;
    SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT p.*
        ,b.id as brand
        ,b.name as brandname
        ,j.id as closed
        ,c.name as customername
        ,l.name as productline
        ,u.user_name as username
        ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,j1.min_start,j1.max_delivery) as total_hours
        ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,min_start,now()) as interval_hours
        ,j1.min_start
        ,j1.max_delivery
        ,now()
        ,j2.allclosed
        ,j3.closed
        
        FROM project AS p
        left join customer as c on c.id = p.customer
        left join brand as b on b.id = c.brand 
        left join customer_product_line as l on l.id = p.product_line
        left join users as u on u.id = p.created_by
        left join (select project_id,`status`,id from job where `status` <> 1 group by project_id,`status`) as j on j.project_id = p.id
        left join (select project_id,MIN(start_date) AS min_start,MAX(delivery_date) AS max_delivery,ifnull(count(id),0) as closed from job GROUP BY project_id ) as j1 on j1.project_id = p.id
        left join (select project_id,ifnull(count(id),0) as allclosed from job GROUP BY project_id ) as j2 on j2.project_id = p.id left join (select project_id,ifnull(count(id),0) as closed from job where status = 1 GROUP BY project_id ) as j3 on j3.project_id = p.id 
        
        WHERE ",@declared_in_param, " order by p.id desc LIMIT ",@lim,"  OFFSET ",@ofs);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END"
```

help me to run it from php page

```
call projects_view(20,0, "(p.created_at >= '2023-09-01' AND 
     p.created_at <= '2023-09-17')")
```

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'

Comment: 1) You use `declared_in_param` local variable which is defined nowhere. 2) `+` in MySQL is arithmetic operator strictly. You must use CONCAT() function.

Comment: I Corrct the code but i have erro when run from page "<p>Type: mysqli_sql_exception</p>
<p>Message: Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'</p>
<p>Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php</p>"

Comment: I don't think that error could come from this code. "in 'field list'" means the problem is in the `SELECT` list, but `created_at` doesn't appear there. It only appears in the `WHERE` condition, and an error there would say "in 'where clause'".

Comment: @Barmar, it might come from their input parameter `vfilter`. They are passing in a string with an SQL expression to be used as extra conditions. They seem to have referenced a column name that doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: @BillKarwin I understand that. But they're only substituting it after `WHERE` in the dynamic SQL, so the error message for that would say "in where clause"

Comment: The error would also happen if you don't quote the expression when calling the procedure.